# How can I bake animations in geometry node(using drivers)?

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes

I driver to translate the position of the cube, and I click Object-Animation-Bake Action to bake it , it works fine.

But when I use driver in Geometry node (for example: using "#frame/24" to drive a roatation value of Rotate Instance Node), and try to bake again. The animation is empty(have keyframes but have no animations).

Why and How can I bake drivers-made animation in geometry node?

Comment: AFAIK you can't. Hopefully they will build something for it like "visual" keyframing.

Comment: @Chris thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

At the moment there is not a way to bake into *Action* (f-curve).

In this simple test of Cube rotation ...

[image]
[image]

You can convert into **Shape Keys** per frame by exporting as **Light Wave Point Cache** (.mdd) format.

Enable export addon under *Preferences* and export selected object as *.mdd*. With the Cube selected (without modifier) *Import* .mdd back.

[image]

Or export object as **Alembic** (.abc) file format and import back ... stored under **Mesh Sequence** modifier.

[image]

That is not the same as baked action into f-curves), but it is what it is :)